# Undefined references to powl and log10 even though -lm is used (Trusty via Travis)

Tags: 14.04, compiling, c

When compiling C files with `cc -lm -std=c99 ...` in Trusty, I get the following error:

```
fraction_math.c:(.text+0x5cb): undefined reference to `powl'

/tmp//fetlang_build//fet_obj_debug//core/chain.c.o: In function `num_to_cstr':

chain.c:(.text+0x682): undefined reference to `log10'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However, I can do the exact same build in Debian Stretch or macOS Sierra, and it will find the symbols.

Comment: See [Why does the order of '-l' option in gcc matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893996/why-does-the-order-of-l-option-in-gcc-matter)

Comment: Ayy - putting `-lm` after everything else fixed it. You should put that in answer form and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

Adding this here from a comment as it was not posted as an answer. Had to read the comments to resolve the issue. I was working on regldg (http://regldg.com/docs/command_line_args.php) which had the same issue. I did add `#include "stdint.h"` in the code, but I suspect adding `-lm` after the command manually is what fixed the problem

> "putting -lm after everything else fixed it."

For regldg, the solution was:

```
gcc -O3 -Wall -g alt.o altlist.o build_structs.o char_set.o data.o debug.o grouplist.o grouprecord.o main.o memory.o parse_regex.o program_args.o re_perm.o silist.o tnode.o vlr.o vlrlist.o -o regldg -lm
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps:
1. Open Terminal on your file Location
2. Command -->  gcc filename.c -lm
3. a.out File is Created on your file location
4. Execute The File Command --> ./a.out
5. View on the Output